# How can I wait for $http response before continuing with angular.forEach loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm making an AJAX request for each item in a loop, the end REST service can only perform one request at a time so I need the loop to wait for each request to complete before continuing with the next. How do I do this?

For reference, the end service is performing update tasks on DynamoDB tables - only one table can be modified at once hence my requirement to wait until I get a response before continuing. I could send them all to the server in one hit and handle there, although that makes it hard to receive feedback when each update is completed.

```
angular.forEach($scope.someArray,
  function (value) {

      var postdata = {
        bla: value
      };

      $http.post('/some_url', postdata)
        .then(
        function(result) {
          console.log("Success.");
        },
        function(data) {
          console.log("Failure.");
        }
      );

  }
);
```

Comment: Can you send the entire array back, and bring back an array with a single request rather than looping?

Comment: I could do that I guess, but I'd rather do them individually so I can show feedback when each completes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must make one request at a time (are you sure there isn't a more efficient alternative?), then you'll have to use something other than `Angular.forEach`.

What about something like this (you will need to inject `$q`):

```
function doWhateverWithAll(someArray) {
  // Mark which request we're currently doing
  var currentRequest = 0;
  // Make this promise based.
  var deferred = $q.deferred();
  // Set up a result array
  var results = []
  function makeNextRequest() {
    // Do whatever you need with the array item.
    var postData = someArray[currentRequest].blah;

    $http.post('some/url', postData)
    .then( function (data){
      // Save the result.
      results.push(data);
      // Increment progress.
      currentRequest++;
      // Continue if there are more items.
      if (currentRequest < someArray.length){
        makeNextRequest();
      }
      // Resolve the promise otherwise.
      else {
        deferred.resolve(results);  
      }  
    });
    // TODO handle errors appropriately.
  }
  // return a promise for the completed requests
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then, in your controller/service, you can do the following:

```
doWhateverWithAll($scope.someArray)

.then(function(results){
  // deal with results.
});
```

Comment: I'm updating DynamoDB tables - unfortunately only one operation can be done at a time so the only other way would be to post them all and handle the problem on the server. Your solution works well for me needs because I can individually return feedback when each table has been updated.

Answer (score 10):

Do you really need the forEach? I would not use it and go for something like that:

```
function req(arr) {
  if (angular.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0) {
    var postdata = {
      bla: arr[0]
    };
    $http.post('/some_url', postdata)
      .then(
      function(result) {
        console.log("Success.");
        arr.shift();
        req(arr);
      },
      function(data) {
        console.log("Failure.");
        // if you want to continue even if it fails:
        //arr.shift();
        //req(arr);
      }
    );
  }
}
req($scope.someArray);
```

Comment: `req(arr.shift())` will send the shifted value to the next function call and not new array. Your code should be like this :
`arr.shift();
req(arr);`

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal You're right! Thanks for noticing! I updated the answer.